# How can I dynamicallly start kubernetes pods when the first request arrives?

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, kubernetes-ingress

Let's say I have multiple endpoints in my application that are exposed as different Kubernetes services via an ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service2
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
```

Let us say service2 endpoint does not receive requests for a long time, so a serverless strategy is appropriate for it. Can I configure a Kubernetes ingress controller to dynamically scale service deployments up when a request arrives after a long time to service2 and shut down the pods for service2 when no request arrives for a long time?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx ingress can not be used for serverless. You can use [knative](https://knative.dev/docs/) for this use case.

Comment: Thank you. knative does seem like a good fit! 

Do you have any additional pointers on how knative can be configured to use the count of calls to a service as the metric to use to auto scale the pods? I am not clear on how knative can become aware of the number of calls to a service?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ingress controller can auto scale pods. Look at kubernetes autoscalar (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), this can be used to horizontally scale pods of your deployment (or other resources where replicas can be specified).

Answer (score 0):

Check the custom metrics support added to HorizontalPodAutoscalar.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics

Your application could expose a custom metric (e.g. a number of HTTP requests) to a collector say Prometheus which then feeds these custom metrics to the Prometheus Adapter (a custom API server).

Not sure if you could start with 0 replicas and scale to 1 (and above) when a first request arrives.